# Why the cdrom has not detected by qemu system armv7?

Tags: qemu, armv7

I created a qemu system with virtual machine manager, when I first boot, it detects scsi cdrom and boots from, but when I reset the system it no longer does detects it. What is the problem

Qeme system EFI Internal Shell devices output:
Shell> devices
T   D
Y C I
P F A
CTRL E G G #P #D #C  Device Name
==== = = = == == === =========================================================
15 R - -  0  1   1 VenHw(D3987D4B-971A-435F-8CAF-4967EB627241)/Uart(38400,8,N,1)
7F D - -  1  0   0 Primary Console Input Device
80 D - -  1  0   0 Primary Console Output Device
81 D - -  1  0   0 Primary Standard Error Device
B4 B - -  1  5   3 VT-100 Serial Console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHgAR.png)

`

I removed scsi controller and tried sata cdrom, but didn't detected it either.